# Finality 502 blocks behind production on our relay testnet

Tags: rococo, relay-chain, finality, finalization

After fixing stalled finality which was due to 5 of 13 valdidators broken, finality is now 502 blocks behind, but it is not catching up to production.

We get this error:

```
2022-09-29 20:13:03 Safeguard enforced finalization of child forced_target=0xd0df478b4bf96df1871fa22890f73c526c4d79b840496c9543bb2b080009e5ca
```

[image]

You can view the chain here: https://apps.decentration.org/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpopart1.jelliedowl.com#/explorer

It seems like block production may have also gone into a “slow mode” because finality is so far behind?

We are running Rococo `release-v0.9.26-1`

How can we remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

You can send:

```
Initializer::ForceApprove(Root, HighestBlock)
```

Send this as transaction to the chain and it should start finalizing.

Comment: ForceApprove is different than forcing a GRANDPA set change, which is perhaps what's needed?

Comment: i tried to forcApprove up to 5 blockcs behind the best block, but i didnt see any change. Then i try Grandpa noteStalled, but still finalized blocks are 500 behind, with 1 minute blocks. Perhaps i need to wait for session change?

Comment: Now it looks like it is completely down?

Comment: yes it’s down, sigh, I think that would have bricked it, because of babe, now must restart I assume.

Comment: Yes, the nodes are now doing this:

///  New epoch 4268 launching at block 0xc6ba…0e95 (block slot 277502581 >= start slot 277494208).

///  Next epoch starts at slot 277494808

/// Not applying authority set change forced at block #2158588, due to pending standard change at block #2158105

/// Error with block built on 0xe9abb0102d2e059a4a56ca30ce99e6027873aa274ffc423babe72f43cd40b1d9: Import failed: A pending forced authority set change could not be applied since it must be applied after the pending standard change at #2158105

Comment: Oh, yes.  Stackexchange doesn't do formatting in comments, does it?

Comment: Possibly the parameters on the extrinsic weren't right?  
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpopart1.jelliedowl.com#/extrinsics/decode/0xd10184002e25b97b6ea3d9ea70d82e7896a8979483185186f853d5a7614d2dcfd983477c01a26809d84c86ae84b05d23e8875765930005dfc0c61beb40a7fe800c42d5822ede6e2db9011be712cd184a6604543ca63a5e4c7107dbb31bf8cbc1dd8e5cd68f25026d010020000a0200000000d4ef2000

Comment: Next time I propose that you read the docs of the extrinsic before sending it.Using `delay` of `0` is wrong.